# Split() with multiple delimiters(Not working)

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, parsing

So I have a file to which I have written into an array. I wanted to parse the string by splitting it into smaller strings. I have used split("\s+") to separate a string from another string by any space. However I wanted to also include `(";,.\n:()")` as delimiters. Can someone help me? I have tried `split(".,;:\n()\\s+")` but this produces a way wrong result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this,

```
str.split("[.,;:\\n()]|\\s+");
```

character class should take each token as separate delimiters. Above should do splitting according to the characters present inside the character  present inside the character class or it would do splits on one or more space characters.

*or*

Since `\\s` also matches `\\n`, I just combined the both..

```
str.split("[.,;:()\\s]+");
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. What is the reason behind using [  ] and the + following the brackets?

Comment: @FutureUIUXDeveloper without `+`, `foo()bar` would produce, `foo`, `empty`, `empty`, `bar`. And with plus, it should produce `foo`, `bar` . ie, it would do splitting on one or more character present inside the character class.

Comment: @FutureUIUXDeveloper [Accept if my answer seems helpful..](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: * The first expression returns only 1 empty token: `"foo"`, `empty`, `"bar"`